# array reference expected exception in java

Tags: java, arrays

Im just trying to create a new 2d array using existing 2d array call `properties` and new two values which is `sourceURL` and `fetchURL`.

```
public static String[][] setProperties(String[][] properties, String sourceURL, String fetchURL) {
        String[][] propertyArray = new String[properties.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i <= properties.length; i++) {
            if (i < properties.length) {
                propertyArray[i][0] = properties[i][0];
                propertyArray[i][1] = properties[i][1];
            } else {
                propertyArray[properties.length][0] = sourceURL;
                propertyArray[properties.length][1] = fetchURL;
                return propertyArray;
            }
        }
        return new String[0][];
    }
```

while I'm doing this I'm getting an exception saying "array reference expected" in the `propertyArray[i][0] = properties[i][0];` line. Can some one help me to create this function?

Comment: How are you calling it? Specifically, what are you passing for `properties`?

Comment: `propertyArray[properties.length][0] = sourceURL;` should give you an index out of bounds exception. `propertyArray[properties.length - 1][0] = sourceURL;` Because it counts the ammount of things in the array, but the array starts at 0 not 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you haven't set the second dimension size of the array. probably it will throw `NullPointerException`

```
String[][] propertyArray = new String[properties.length][2];
```

Also you you missed a logic

- your loop runs `properties.length+1` times. So better to change size to `properties.length+1`

> `String[][] propertyArray = new String[properties.length+1][2];`

Comment: this was the problem .,. now its working thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think this:

```
String[][] propertyArray = new String[properties.length][];
for (int i = 0; i <= properties.length; i++) {
    if (i < properties.length) {
       propertyArray[i][0] = properties[i][0];
```

Is wrong and you may have a similar issue before you call the method you listed.

You are constructing a propertyArray of size [x][]  which means the second dimension doesn't exist.
calling propertyArray[i][0] should result in an error. 
you should first create an array at the location you want to access it

```
propertyArray[i] = new String[properties[i].length];
```

Furthermore you run i from 0 till properties.length (which means properties[i] = array index out of bounds)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
String[][] propertyArray = new String[properties.length + 1][];
```

You're trying to add an extra property, so you need one more element than you're given.